# Low fps on SKScene when applying CIFilter iOS9

Tags: sprite-kit, ios9, skscene, cifilter

I'm using Sprit Kit for my game. And I'm using black and white CIFilter for the scene. So the point is that fps was 60 on iOS 8. When I updated to iOS 9.0 the fps drops to 20 when I apply filter on SKScene. Maybe I do something wrong? What is wrong with iOS 9.0???

Here's my code:

```
- (void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view
{
    self.filter = [self blackAndWhiteFilter];
    self.shouldEnableEffects = YES;
}

- (CIFilter *)blackAndWhiteFilter
{
    CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorControls"];

    [filter setDefaults];
    [filter setValue:@0 forKey:@"inputSaturation"];

    return filter;
}
```

P.S. Low fps on device, not on simulator

Comment: On which devices are you testing? Simulator FPS is not representative.

Comment: On device, I have noticed the same drop in frame rate with a blur filter I added to my scene. In iOS 8, it was fine and your filter looks like you are doing it correctly. My guess is, since iOS 9 uses Metal, there is a bug with filters. I opened a ticket with Apple and would suggest doing the same to get priority to it.